# Best way of storage delimted values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array that stores an arbitrary set of items for a defined batch. Each item is defined in a separate table with its own properties and values.

Example

- batch 1 contains items 1,3,11,16,17,
- batch 2 contains items 5,11,15.

What is the proper way of storing arrays like that in MySQL?

Currently, I'm storing the items as comma delimited strings in an items column. Whenever I need to retrieve the info, I query that column, split the string into an array, loop through that array, create a new query form the split values, and then run a new query joining in the split values. Surely there must be a better way of doing this?

Example of the table layout:

```
Batches table:
==============
id|items
--------
1 |1,3,11,16,17
2 |5,11,15

Items table:
============
id|description     |serial
--------------------------
1 |some description|00046552
2 |etc             |00046653
3...
```

Comment: You should read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the data as a many-to-many relationship:

```
Batches table:
==============
id | Batch description
---+------------------
 1 | Some description
 2 | Some other desc...


Items table:
============
id|description     |serial
--+----------------+------
1 |some description|00046552
2 |etc             |00046653
3...

Batch items:
============
batch_id | item_id
---------+--------
 1       |  1
 1       |  3
 1       | 11
 1       | 16
 1       | 17
 2       |  5
 2       | 11
 2       | 15
```

If the order of items in a batch is important, you can add another column to `Batch items` table to indicate an order within a batch; or simply use item id as the ordering column.

This way you can you can enforce referential integrity using foreign keys and make it so much easier to manipulate individual items within a batch.

Comment: Very simple and to the point. Why didn't I think of this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad design to store comma separated value in a column. Normalize the database properly. Convert the table into 2-table design if the relationship of `Items` to `Batches` is `One-to-many`.

Example,

**Items**

- ItemID (PK)
- Description
- Serial

**Batches**

- BatchID
- ItemID (FK)

But if you have `Many-to-many` relationship, consider adding new table that links between the two.

Items

- ItemID (PK)
- Description
- Serial

Batches

- BatchID (PK)
- otherColumns...

Batch_Item

- BatchID (FK)  -- unique pair with ItemID
- ItemID (FK)

Comment: My understanding is that he's already using two tables, he's just trying to keep one row per `id` as 1:1, where this is clearly 1:N relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The 'SQL correct' method would be to have multiple rows per `id` and use a combined `PRIMARY KEY` of `id` and `item` like:

```
id| item
--------
1 | 1
1 | 3
1 | 11
...
2 | 15
```

I'm not sure if this would increase performance overall. Either way you're going to be looping an array, you cut out the step of turning a delimited list into an array but you add more database rows and more  results to the `SELECT` statement.